# Flask-Admin - what to pass in url_for(' ')?

Tags: flask, flask-admin

I got an error, that says, that no URL can be build from that parameter inside url_for('').

I passed url_for('admin') but that does not work. What should I pass to get to localhost:5000/admin ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You pass the name of the definition of the route you want to visit.

For example:

```
@app.route('/')
def index():
    return 'Hello, World!'

...

@app.route('/some_page')
def somewhere_else():
    if something_happened:
        redirect(url_for('index'))
    
    return render_template('some_page.html')
```

Or if you are using it inside your HTML:

```
<a href="{{ url_for('index') }} ...></a>
```

Comment: Thank you, I understand that concept, but how does it work for the /admin route? what is the default definition from the /admin route of flask-admin?

Comment: I got it: url_for('admin.index') got to the index page.